# Ordered sequence of operations in restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

I use the following code to start N requests, where every request is made of two request that must go hand-by-hand ( I do not care of blocking the UI because I want the app blocked):

```
objectManager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
{
[objectManager postObject:reqObj
                         path:@"sync.json"
                   parameters:nil 
                      success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                        [operation waitUntilFinished];
                        // Do something and then send the second request
                        [self sendAck];
            } // end success
                    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}
];

}
```

And the second request is very similar:

```
 -(void)sendAck
    {
    [objectManager postObject:reqObj
                             path:@"sync.json"
                       parameters:nil
                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                               [operation waitUntilFinished];

    }
    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}
    ]

    }
```

But after checking the logs at the server I realized that all the "acks", I mean all the second requests come after all the first requests. And the results are obviously incorrect.
If a request i is started, we must wait the second request to finish before sending the i+1 request. That is:

```
req. i, second req. on i, req. i+1, second req. on i+ 1,...
```

and not

```
req .i ,req. i+1, ....., second req. on i, second req. on i+1
```

The use of operation queue is wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: _"I do not care of blocking the UI because I want the app blocked"_ A user won't - and Apple may reject it.

Comment: `[operation waitUntilFinished]` possibly has no effect, since the operation is always finished when the completion handler will be executed. Do I miss something?

Comment: The operation is a synchronization process and must not be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this, but a good way to ensure that you are calling the requests in a specific order is by placing them in a queue like described [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#manage-a-queue-of-object-request-operations).

Another approach is make the calls synchronous, a good way to do it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768287/make-a-synchronous-http-call-with-restkit).

Comment: The first link does the same of my code, if u inspect what postObject does u will notice that it enqueue request, as in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Using "recursion", i.e. eliminating the for loop and using a global variabile which counts the number of total requests is a better approach, as in this answer [of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993954/restkit-process-one-rest-operation-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is how you use the `NSOperationQueue:

In the for loop you are effectively *enqueueing* N "send" requests. All are executed in order and sequentially.

When the first request got finished, the next "send" request will be executed. Since the first "send" request is finished you *enqueue* the corresponding "sendAck". That is, it will be *appended* to the tail of the queue, where other "send" requests are still waiting.

When the second "send "request get finished, the next "send" request will be executed and so on. Since the second "send" request is finished you *enqueue* the corresponding "sendAck" and so force.

When all "send" requests have been executed, the first "sendAck" request gets send. When it finished, the next "sendAck" will be executed and so force until all "sendAck" requests have eventually been send.

Comment: And which is the solution to get what I want?

Comment: @giuseppe First off, don't run a for loop. Instead, put the requests (or URLs and params) as an object into an NSMutableArray. Start the first request and remove it from the array. In the completion handler, remove the first from the array (which is now the second) and start that request and the corresponding ack from the first request. This "looks like" a recursion, but in fact isn't.